# Default Startup scripts

Tags: 12.04, startup, startup-applications

I just installed unclutter on Ubuntu 12.04, Gnome 3, but it uses standard settings, and there is no way i can change them from terminal, not to mention i need to apply them from the very start.

I think the only way is to find Unclutter in the default script that runs it. But I dont know where it is and where to find it.

It is not in the startup applications, I checked.

Comment: Hey, I guess you got the tumbleweed badge for this question, which is a shame because it is a very tricky question for those who have it. I searched my whole home directory with `rgrep -I unclutter /home/` only to find that actually the configuration is system-wide. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, by default, `unclutter`'s startup configuration affects all users, and is in this file:

```
/etc/default/unclutter
```

I suggest you set:

```
START_UNCLUTTER="false"
```

and then configure your personal preference in Startup Applications.

Alternatively, you can leave `START_UNCLUTTER` set to `true`, and set `EXTRA_OPTS` to your preference, but be warned that this will affect *all* users of the system, which is almost always undesirable for multi-user systems, and may cause the kind of confusion as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3022/weird-mouse-problem).